# Feature Selection Valid or not?

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection

I have a question in mind. I built a dependent variable y based on other features say m and n in my dataset and I want to build a model and train it.But I am not sure if I can include m and n in the training of model? As when I do this I get almost 99% accuracy and other metrics. \Is it valid that I only use other features  that I did not use for construction the y?

 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the functional relationship between `y` and its depedent variables `m` and `n`?  I know that in the case of random forests we used to drop variables sometimes which were highly correlated, because redundant variables do not add anything to the model.

Comment: So the logic here is that I am making y(churntype) as a factor yes or no based on the marginal difference in frequency and money between two time frames and if this marginal value is less than 50 then I make that user as yes type and otherwise no.
<br>In this case, I am building a model to train and predict the churntype based on other features.Here is it logical to use the marginal freq and value for building the model. Hope its clear!